# Check if more than 30 minutes has passed

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm working on a small project and I've run into some trouble.
The issue is that I want to check if there has been more than 30 minutes since a `u_latest_activity` latest was updated, if there's been, then update and set `u_online=0`
The field in the MySQL database is a datetime field.
I have no PHP code to show yet since none that I've tried has worked, I tried using the DateTime object but I'm clueless about how it works. I googled alot but I still couldn't figure it out so I use this as a last resort. I'll gladly accept a SQL solution as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you actually need the value `u_online` for? If it's for checking how many people are online, just query the database how many values of `u_latest_activity` are within the last half hour...?

Comment: I'm checking the users status to show if they're online or not in their profile and if they haven't been active in 30 minutes I want to set their status to offline. It's for a community project I'm working on to improve my php skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE your_table SET u_online = 0 WHERE u_latest_activity < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great, will set you as accepted answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

this is pure mySQL ans might help

```
SELECT if(DATE_ADD(u_latest_activity, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) > NOW() , 1 , 0) as u_online from mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only selects all the rows, I want to select and update the rows.

Comment: I did, thank you for your answer though. I can still learn from your example.

Comment: I would suggest using "DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)" (which is constant) instead of Your "DATE_ADD(u_latest_activity, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)" since MySQL cannot use any index (if it exists) on the "u_latest_activity" in Your expression. See my fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a8e/4

Comment: you are right. but since i am not using any `WHERE` clause this issue will not affect my code snippet.

Comment: but in fact i am glad you pointed that out. otherwise the kids would have not learned that. and your sqlfiddle is very helpful. i wish it would be possible to mark a comment as "accepted" ;-)